# guild.text_channels return just the top channel instead of all channels

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot and I want it to send a message whenever it joins a new guild.

However, I only want it to send the message in the `#general` channel of the guild it joins:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    chans = guild.text_channels
    for channel in chans:
        if channel.name == 'general':
            await channel.send('hi')
        break
```

The problem that I have noticed is that `guild.text_channels` only returns the name of the very first channel of the server. I want to iterate through all channels and finally send message only on the `#general` channel.

What's the workaround for it?

Comment: Guild.text_channels should return a list of TextChannel, how do you know it's not getting them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

Here's an example using `utils.get()`:

```py
import discord # To access utils.get

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name="general")
    await channel.send("Hi!")
```

Or if the guild has a `system_channel` set up, you can send a message there:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    await guild.system_channel.send("Hi!")
```

You can create checks for both of these, but bear in mind that some servers might not have a text channel called `general` or a system channel set up, so you may receive some attribute errors complaining about `NoneType` not having a `.send()` attribute.

These errors can be avoided with either an error handler or a `try`/`except`.

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.system_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.system_channel)
- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)